# Vuex - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

Why do I get this error:

> Error [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

**What does it mean?**

It happens when I try to type in the **edit input file**.

`pages/todos/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="todo.done" v-on:change="toggle(todo)">
      <span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{ todo.text }}</span>
      <button class="destroy" v-on:click="remove(todo)">delete</button>

      <input class="edit" type="text" v-model="todo.text" v-todo-focus="todo == editedTodo" @blur="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.enter="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.esc="cancelEdit(todo)">

    </li>
    <li><input placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus v-model="todo" v-on:keyup.enter="add"></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      todo: '',
      editedTodo: null
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.$route.params.slug || 'all',
      titleTemplate: 'Nuxt TodoMVC : %s todos'
    }
  },
  fetch ({ store }) {
    store.commit('todos/add', 'Hello World')
  },
  computed: {
    todos () {
      // console.log(this)
      return this.$store.state.todos.list
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add (e) {

      var value = this.todo && this.todo.trim()
      if (value) {
        this.$store.commit('todos/add', value)
        this.todo = ''
      }

    },
    toggle (todo) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/toggle', todo)
    },
    remove (todo) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/remove', todo)
    },

    doneEdit (todo) {
      this.editedTodo = null
      todo.text = todo.text.trim()
      if (!todo.text) {
        this.$store.commit('todos/remove', todo)
      }
    },
    cancelEdit (todo) {
      this.editedTodo = null
      todo.text = this.beforeEditCache
    },
  },
  directives: {
    'todo-focus' (el, binding) {
      if (binding.value) {
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

`stores/todos.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  list: []
})

export const mutations = {
  add (state, text) {
    state.list.push({
      text: text,
      done: false
    })
  },
  remove (state, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
  },
  toggle (state, todo) {
    todo.done = !todo.done
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You can just turn off Vuex strict mode.

Comment: @Xhua the strict mode is here for a reason (better practices), rather keep it to have cleaner code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It could be a bit tricky to use v-model on a piece of state that belongs to Vuex.

and you have used `v-model` on `todo.text` here:

```html
<input class="edit" type="text" v-model="todo.text" v-todo-focus="todo == editedTodo" @blur="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.enter="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.esc="cancelEdit(todo)">
```

use `:value` to read value and `v-on:input` or `v-on:change` to execute a method that perform the mutation inside an explicit Vuex mutation handler

This issue is handled here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Comment: thanks. I have read that. but this example is fine using `v-model` - https://github.com/nuxt/todomvc/blob/master/pages/_slug.vue?

Comment: I recommend using data with v-model for forms in vuex.

Answer (score 29):

Hello I have get the same problem and solve it with clone my object using one of the following:

```js
{ ...obj} //spread syntax 
Object.assign({}, obj)
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

For your code I think you need to replace this part

```js
computed: {
  todos () {
    // console.log(this)
    return this.$store.state.todos.list
  }
}
```

With this

```js
computed: {
  todos () {
    // console.log(this)
    return {...this.$store.state.todos.list}
  }
}
```

I don't make sure if this is the best way but hope this helpful for other people that have the same issue.

Comment: OK for display but to set the value back, still have to make each field mutation (set new value)

Answer (score 14):

This error may come from the fact you [shallow cloned an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).
Meaning that you've tried to copy an object but an object is not a primitive type (like `String` or `Number`), hence it's passed by reference and not value.
Here you think that you cloned one object into the other, while you are still referencing the older one. Since you're **mutating the older one**, you got this nice warning.

Here is a GIF from [Vue3's documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) (still relevant in our case).
On the left, it's showing an object (mug) being not properly cloned >> passed by reference.
On the right, it's properly cloned >> passed by value. Mutating this one does not mutate the original

[image]

---

The proper way to manage this error is to use `lodash`, this is how to load it **efficiently** in Nuxt:

- Install `lodash-es`, eg: `yarn add lodash-es`, this is an optimized tree-shakable [lodash ES module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)
- you may also need to transpile it in your `nuxt.config.js` with the following

```js
build: {
  transpile: ['lodash-es'],
}
```

- load it into your `.vue` components like this

```html
<script>
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es'

...
const properlyClonedObject = cloneDeep(myDeeplyNestedObject)
...
</script>
```

---

Few keys points:

- lodash is recommended over `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` because it does handle [some edge-cases](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/#wrong-solutions)
- we only load small functions from lodash and not the whole library thanks to this setup, so there is no penalty in terms of performance
- lodash has a lot of well battle-tested useful functions, which is heavily lacking in JS (no core library)
- **UPDATE**: [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) is also native and quite performant if you're looking for a solution for a deep copy, bypassing the need for Lodash at all.

Answer (score 7):

There is no headache if you can use lodash

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    todo: (state) => _.cloneDeep(state.todo)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone's still being troubled by this,
I got my code working by making a duplicate/clone of the store state.

In your case, try something like this...

```js
computed: {
  todos () {
    return [ ...this.$store.state.todos.list ]
  }
}
```

It's basically a spread operator which results in making a clone of the todos.list array. With that, you're not directly changing the values of your state, just don't forget commit so your mutations will be saved in the store.

Comment: But this answer is already given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65651645/5468463

Answer (score 2):

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    ...
    strict: true
})
```

try to comment "strict"

Comment: Thanks. this worked for me in my case.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with this issue for hours... Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vuex **Modules**, you might bump into this error if your module's `data` property is an object, instead of a function that returns an object, and you are sharing this Module between more than one Store.

So instead of:

```js
// In stores/YourModule.js
export default {
  state: { name: 'Foo' },
}
```

Change it to:

```js
// In stores/YourModule.js
export default {
  state: () => {
    return { name: 'Foo' };
  },
}
```

This is actually documented [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse):

> Sometimes we may need to create multiple instances of a module, for
> example:
>
> Creating multiple stores that use the same module (e.g. To avoid
> stateful singletons in the SSR (opens new window)when the
> runInNewContext option is false or 'once'); Register the same module
> multiple times in the same store. If we use a plain object to declare
> the state of the module, then that state object will be shared by
> reference and cause cross store/module state pollution when it's
> mutated.
>
> This is actually the exact same problem with data inside Vue
> components. **So the solution is also the same - use a function for
> declaring module state** (supported in 2.3.0+):

Answer (score 0):

If your data is an array with objects inside. Below snippet is the solution

```
const toyData = await this.$store.dispatch(
    `user/fetchCoinToys`,
    payload
)
const msgList = toyData.msglist.map((data) => {
    return { ...data }
})
```

Comment: Spread operator will only make a shallow copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add mutation and call it instead of setting directly.

wrong:

```
someAction({state, rootState}) {
    state.someValue = true;
}
```

right:

```
mutations: {
    ...
    setSomeValue(state, val) {
        state.someValue = val;
    },
    ...
}
...
someAction({state, commit, rootState}) {
    commit('setSomeValue', true);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not your case but if someone is using typescript and is having the same problem, adding `this: any` as the first param in your method or somewhere else should fix the problem