# Nuxt / Vue - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a simple cart store, to add / remove items.

When you add a product to the cart, I show a flash message with the possibility to update the quantity. Since I don't know which product is concerned in my flash message component, I use the store.

I have a simple bootstrap spinner :

```
    <b-form-spinbutton
      :value="value"
      min="1"
      max="26"
      @change="setItems"
    />
```

When I change this, I want to call the `setItems` function of my store to update the last item added.

So I used :

```
  data () {
    return {
      value: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setItems (value) {
      const items = [...this.$store.getters['cart/items']]
      // update quantity of the last item - we suppose it's the current item
      items.slice(-1)[0].quantity = value
      this.$store.commit('cart/setItems', items)
    }
  }
```

I read about this error here : [Vuex - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044276/vuex-do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers), so I changed `v-model` to `value` approach.

My store `cart.js` is :

```
export const state = () => ({
  items: []
})

export const mutations = {
  setItems (state, items) {
    state.items = items
  },
  // ....
```

I can't figure how to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line were the store state is mutated outside mutation handler is:

```
items.slice(-1)[0].quantity = value
```

By using spread operator you create a shallow copy of store items. each item property still references the vuex state. you can create a deep copy, with:

```
const items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters['cart/items']))
```

Or, if you have lodash in your project:

```
const items = _.cloneDeep(this.$store.getters['cart/items'])
```

Comment: Oh ok ! because I tried other methods to clone my object using reduce or map I saw on internet, but your method clearly works and it was indeed this, thanks !

Comment: Lodash is recommended because of some rare issues with the stringify solution.