# Vuex mutation throws an error - do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, mutation

I have a Vuex store object which has a mutation.

```
SET_FILTERS_CATEGORIES(state, payload) {
    state.filters.categories = payload;
},

SET_FILTERS_CATEGORIES(state, payload) {
    // state.filters.categories = payload;  // This "works"
},
```

This mutation throws me an error:

> do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

If I commented this line it "works". I dont understand what is the problem. It is inside the mutation section.

Comment: Can you share your Vue component that calls the mutation?

Comment: It has 1800rows. This is the code, which throws an error.

Comment: @Čamo How are you calling the mutation? That's the code we're looking for.

Comment: Mutation is called from store action.

Comment: Please show some relevant and concrete code. We can't help you with just this. Also, did you looked up for this question anywhere? This might be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46044276/8816585

Comment: That link is related to problem with model in inputs. This is not the case. I really dont have any more relevant code. This is the line which throws an error. The question is why? Is there a problem with nested items in payload? Thats the question.

Comment: Nested items in payload wouldn't cause this problem. The key is the code that invokes the mutation. Can you update this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-mutate-vuex-data?file=store/products.js) to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you must call your **mutation** only inside action method.

code exemple

```js
const mutations = {
  SET_FILTERS_CATEGORIES(state, payload) {
      state.filters.categories = payload;
  },
}

const actions = {
  getFiltersCategories ({commit}, payload){
    commit('SET_FILTERS_CATEGORIES', payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do it this way. However it throws an error.

Comment: it throws the same error ?
let me see where you call SET_FILTERS_CATEGORIES in your code

Comment: I call it in the actions section. There is an action for it.

Comment: cand i see your code ?