# Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers because of v-if v-else

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I think I do not mutate any vuex store outside mutation handlers but I still got this error
May be its because of my v-if, v-else.
This is my code:

```
<v-btn
    v-if="$store.state.cart.user.email == '' && loginButtonVisible"
    nuxt
    to="/login"
    min-width="100"
    icon
  >
    <v-icon size="20">mdi-account-outline</v-icon>
    <p style="margin: 0" class="text-capitalize">Login</p>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn
    v-else-if="$store.state.cart.user.email == '' && !loginButtonVisible"
    nuxt
    to="/register"
    min-width="100"
    icon
  >
    <v-icon size="20">mdi-account-outline</v-icon>
    <p style="margin: 0" class="text-capitalize">Register</p>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn v-else @click="$store.commit('cart/LogOut')" min-width="100" icon>
    <p style="margin: 0" class="text-capitalize">Logout</p>
    <v-icon size="20">mdi-logout</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
```

And this is my store/state.js file:

```
  export default function (params) {
  return {
    cart: [],
    user: {
      email: "",
      idToken: "",
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044276/vuex-do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers)

Comment: That answer is for the form. I don't know how to change my v-if to other props that my code still work.

Comment: The `v-if` is probably not the culprit as explained in my linked answer. You are mutating your state somewhere. A [repro] would be highly appreciated here IMO.

Comment: I think its this v-if because when I delete the `$store.state.cart.user.email == ''` , I don't get the errors.

Comment: You can try pin-pointing the culprit by looking at the stacktrace of these errors - it might lead you to the code which actually mutates Vuex.