# Nuxt update state not working, "do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm trying to update a state and i get this error:  **Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**.  The following creates state for `categories`.

register.vue , i can see the state `categories` in vuex is updated.

```
async saveCategories(){
    if(this.selectedCategories.length) {
        this.$store.dispatch('app/Categories', this.selectedCategories);
        this.$router.push(`/dashboard`);
    }
  }
```

dashboard.vue, when i try to update the state with new `selectedCategories` in method `updateCategories`, the state `categories` isn't updated when i check vuex in chrome extension

```
async mounted() {    
    if(this.$store.state.app.Categories.length) {
    this.selectedCategories = this.$store.state.app.Categories.map((category: any) => {
        return parseInt(category);
    });
    }
        
  }

   updateCategories() {    
     this.$store.dispatch('app/Categories', this.selectedCategories);
   }
```

I get this error **Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

this is how i access the state  `this.$store.state.app.Categories`

How do i solve?

Comment: Gave a read to that one already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46044276/8816585

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you can do an action in store instead of in a component.
`this.$store.state.app.Categories.map((category: any) => parseInt(category));`

The solution is to create a mutation for this and instead call that mutation in the component.

```js
state: {
  app: {
    Categories: []
  }
}

mutations: {
  toInt(state) {
    state.app.Categories.map((category: any) => parseInt(category))
  }
}
```

**Register.vue**

```js
async mounted() {
  this.$store.commit('toInt')
}
```

Comment: Hi, please do not make it `async mounted`if calling a **sync** mutation. Otherwise, please recommend a Vuex action.